# JSON Schema Dependency based on value

Tags: jsonschema

I need to make a schema that expects a property to exist if another property has a certain value.

```
{"handleFailure":"redirect","redirectUrl":"http://something.com"}
```

and

```
{"handleFailure":"reject"}
```

should both be valid, but

```
{"handleFailure:"redirect"}
```

should not be valid due to the `redirectUrl` property not being present.

I have tried to make a top level `oneOf` with the two schemas like so

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "handleFailure": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "redirect"
          ]
        },
        "redirectUrl": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uri"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "handleFailure": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "reject"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but I get an error about the properties not being defined.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am able to parse your schema and create objects that validate against it. Can you be more specific about the error message you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried putting the additionalProperties flag inside each of the oneOf schemas?

Comment: Thank you, moving the flag resolved it. Can't believe I spent an hour on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the `"additionalProperties": false` flag into the sub schemas to prevent those objects having additional properties.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "handleFailure": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "redirect"
          ]
        },
        "redirectUrl": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uri"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "handleFailure": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "reject"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```